# DACPAC not detecting changes (SSDT)

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I have an SSDT Database project, to which I have added a new field. If I use that DACPAC to generate a new database on my local server, the new field is all present and correct - which is great.

However, if I upgrade a database, then at the point when the system is checking for differences, it reports back that there have been no changes (misses my new field), and of course my new field doesn't appear.

Does anyone know why that would be, or have any thoughts on what it is that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Ridiculous suggestion: you _are_ building the project again (i.e. creating a new `.dacpac` after adding the field in the project, right?

Comment: Right... The same DACPAC includes the new field if it is used to create a new database, but omits it if it is asked to modify an old database...

Comment: What options are you using? Are you sure that you're using the new dacpac in the comparison? Are you sure that the target is set to the correct target?  Hard to say for sure what might be wrong in this case.

Comment: What does it mean by "upgrade database"? Publish it from SSDT project? Then as @PeterSchott suggested go through all the settings and carefully check them. My guess: is that table under replication or cdc?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions everyone. Still having fun with this...